# slideshow position is too low in IE and FF

Tags: css, html, position

I have this slideshow that I'm trying to simply move up, but I can't position it right to get it up.  Right now there is all this white space.  Can someone help me out on where I'm going wrong?  Just view it in Firefox or IE to see the whitespace.  It works in Chrome of course, b/c everything works in chrome.

http://modernd-i.com/

I try to use position in css but in these browsers it doesn't budge.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IT looks like you're using a table for the layout. the `<td>` that contains the image gallery has an a vertical alignment set to `vertical-align: baseline;` if you change that in the html to `valign="top"` it will make it work. Checked it in Firefox, not IE.

Comment: That's it!  thank you.  How do you guys even spot that stuff?   I would have been here all day for something so little.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In your styles.css, line 4 you have:

```
...tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent;
border: 0 none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
vertical-align: baseline;   /* this is what is causing it */
}
```

Change that last one to:  `vertical-align: top`

Baseline as a global declaration isn't the best idea, unless it's intentional.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
#yourslideshow {
    position: relative;
    top: (-X)px;
 }
```

*-X represents the number of pixels.

Since you don't have a jsfiddle I can't tell you exactly how much. But if you use top, that is how many pixels are in between your slideshow and the top of the page. (you could also use bottom, and not use a negative value).

ex.

```
#yourslideshow {
    position: relative;
    bottom: (X)px;
 }
```

I know you said you used position, but I'm not sure which type of position you used since you didn't specify.

THEN

If position still doesn't work, you can try either a positive margin-top or a negative margin-bottom

```
#yourslideshow {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: (X)px;
 }
```

OR

```
#yourslideshow {
    position: relative;
   margin-top: (-X)px;
 }
```